# Sha-bang line gives different result than calling the script manually

Tags: python, shell

I have a Python script `script.py` that has been defined as executable and which begins with the following sha-bang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python -W all
```

But when I call it from the shell, this is what I get:

```
$ ./script.py 
/usr/bin/env: python -W all: No such file or directory
```

Calling it directly works though:

```
$ env python -W all script.py
... some good stuff happens here
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a shebang line, you only get one argument.  So `python -W all` is being passed to `env` as one argument.  On the command line, the shell correctly parses the arguments before invoking `env`.